# -SOLVED- How to upload a photo to WordPress Media Library via WordPress REST API with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, rest, request

Unable to upload a photo to WordPress Media Library via WordPress REST API for the second day.
*WordPress version 6.1.1*
I am well aware that this and similar questions have been raised on StackOverflow many times, I have read probably all of them. I tried to use some of the suggested solutions, but unfortunately, none of the scripts uploaded the photo to WordPress.

## I tried to minimize the code sample I expect to make work*:

```
import requests

photo_data = open("photo.jpg", 'rb').read()
headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=photo.jpg",
           "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}
r = requests.post(url='https://DOMAIN-NAME.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                  auth=('admin', 'APpL IcaT iONp assW ordW Padm'),
                  headers=headers,
                  data=photo_data)
print(r)
```

*.Please note that I have intentionally not shared my account details as well as the domain of my real site.

## So my question is what am I doing wrong and how do I get the code to work?

***PS
All I get in response is data about the photos previously uploaded to WordPress Media Library via dashboard.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get WordPress to accept photo uploads. Below you will see a 100% working basic version of the solution. All you need to do is to replace the **domain**, **username** and **application password** and you will be able to upload photos to your site as well.
Keep in mind that you need to get the application password in advance, which can be obtained directly in the WordPress settings (the password is generated on the fly). This method is suitable for everyone who has installed WordPress version 5.6 or higher.

```
import requests

USER = 'admin'
APPLICATION_PASSWORD = 'APpL IcaT iONp assW ordW Padm'
photo_data = {'file': open('photo.jpg', 'rb')}

response = requests.post(url='https://DOMAIN-NAME.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                         auth=(USER, APPLICATION_PASSWORD),
                         files=photo_data)
print(response.text)
```

You can also use a function that only needs to be filled with arguments:

```
import requests

def upload_photo_to_wp(basic_url, user, application_password, photo_path):
    response = requests.post(url=f'https://{basic_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                             auth=(user, application_password),
                             files={'file': open(photo_path, 'rb')})
    return response
```

This way, you can easily send the photo you want to WordPress Media Library.
*Arguments of the `upload_photo_to_wp` function:*

- **basic_url** is the URL of your website (for example, "your-website.com")
- **user** is the name of your WordPress user who has administrator rights
- **application_password** is the aforementioned password that the WordPress will generate for you (you can get it in the WordPress settings)
- **photo_path** is the path to the local photo file

Comment: Many thanks! Is there a possibility to upload multiple files at once ?